# Error in Scraping the website after making its .exe file

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrap the website using scrapy. I write the logic in python and it works properly in the python terminal. But when I make the .exe file of it and run the .exe file of it. It shows the error. I have tried to get the answer but didn't get it. Can anyone please help me?
The error is :

[This is the error I get after running the .exe file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPKRi.png)

```
    import scrapy


class BBCUrduSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bbcurdu'
    url = ""
    fileName = 'dataFileForAll.csv'
    index = 0

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url)


# Creating code for the 100 news for each category.
    # To BBC Main Page.
    def parse(self, response):
        links = response.xpath("//ul[@class='bbc-11krpir e1lim4kn4']/li[position() >  1 and position() < 8]/a")
        for link in links:
            self.index = 0
            href = response.urljoin(link.xpath(".//@href").get()) # Links of all the categories.
            yield response.follow(url=href, callback=self.getIntoLinks)

    # To Every Individual Category.
    def getIntoLinks(self, response):
        ctgry = response.xpath("//h1[@class='topic-title gel-trafalgar-bold gs-u-pt-alt+ gs-u-pb+']//text()").get() # ctgry = pakistan
        linkks = response.xpath("//article/header/div/h3/a")
        for linkk in linkks:
            href = response.urljoin(linkk.xpath(".//@href").get())
            yield response.follow(url=href, callback=self.getTheFullDetail, meta={'Label':ctgry})

        
        nextLink = response.urljoin(response.xpath("//a[@class='lx-pagination__btn gs-u-mr+ qa-pagination-next-page lx-pagination__btn--rtl lx-pagination__btn--active']/@href").get())
        last6characters = nextLink[(len(nextLink) - 6): len(nextLink)]
        if nextLink and last6characters != "age/12":
            yield scrapy.Request(url=nextLink, callback=self.getIntoLinks)

    # Third function to get the headline and detail of the news.
    def getTheFullDetail(self, response):
        ctgry = response.request.meta['Label']
        heading = response.xpath("//h1[@id='content']//text()").get()
        fullnewsLinks = response.xpath("//div[@class='bbc-4wucq3 e57qer20']/p[@class='bbc-1sy09mr e1cc2ql70']")
        fullnews = ''
        for fullnewslink in fullnewsLinks:
            if fullnewslink.xpath(".//b"):
                fullnews += fullnewslink.xpath(".//b/text()").get()
            else:
                fullnews += fullnewslink.xpath(".//text()").get()

        yield {
            'Category: ':ctgry,
            'Heading: ':heading,
            'Full News: ':fullnews
        }
```

Comment: Share your code here too to understand what is wrong